# add marker to middle of polyline in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping, gis, geojson

I have a leaflet map with polyline data in. The polyline is styled how I want but what I would like is to have a marker at the centre of each line. Is this possible and if so what changes to the below do I need to make?

```
var pathstyling = {
  stroke: true,
  fillColor: "#b5b5b5",
  color: "#b5b5b5",
  weight: 5,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.6,
  dashArray: 10,
};

const path = L.geoJSON(path_line, {
  style: pathstyling,
})
  .bindPopup(function (layer) {
    let cap_name = layer.feature.properties.name.replace(
      /(^\w{1})|(\s+\w{1})/g,
      (letter) => letter.toUpperCase()
    );
    return `<p>${cap_name}</p><a href="https://${layer.feature.properties.link}" target="_blank">View<a>`;
    /******/
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#length then https://turfjs.org/docs/#along

Comment: hi @IvanSanchez - I haven't used turf before so not sure how this would look. I'll take a look though and try and get my head around it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with leaflet core:

```
function calcMiddleLatLng(map, latlng1, latlng2) {
    // calculate the middle coordinates between two markers
    const p1 = map.project(latlng1);
    const p2 = map.project(latlng2);
    return map.unproject(p1._add(p2)._divideBy(2));
}
  
function createMiddleMarkers(line){
    var latlngs = line.getLatLngs();
  
  for(var i = 1; i < latlngs.length; i++){
    var left = latlngs[i-1];
    var right = latlngs[i];
    var newLatLng = calcMiddleLatLng(map,left,right);
    L.marker(newLatLng).addTo(map);
  }  
}

createMiddleMarkers(layer);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/g7e8w9tz/